# Linq group the columns combination to a two list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, aggregation

I have question about how I could use Linq grouping the same combination that the list has then relate to a two list.

Example:

**I have theses classes.**

```cs
public class PetCategoryOwner
{
    public string PetCategory { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}

public class PetCategoriesOwners
{
    public IEnumerable<string> PetCategories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

**The example data.**

| Owner | Pet Category |
| --- | --- |
| Higa | Terry |
| Higa | Charlotte |
| Oliver | Terry |
| Oliver | Charlotte |
| Oliver | Chausie |
| Price | Chausie |
| Liam | Terry |
| Liam | Chartreux |

```cs
var petCategoryOwner = new List<PetCategoryOwner>()
{
    new PetCategoryOwner { Owner = "Higa", PetCategory = "Terry"},
    new PetCategoryOwner { Owner = "Higa", PetCategory = "Charlotte"},
    new PetCategoryOwner { Owner = "Oliver", PetCategory = "Terry"},
    new PetCategoryOwner { Owner = "Oliver", PetCategory = "Charlotte"},
    new PetCategoryOwner { Owner = "Oliver", PetCategory = "Chausie"},
    new PetCategoryOwner { Owner = "Price", PetCategory = "Chausie"},
    new PetCategoryOwner { Owner = "Liam", PetCategory = "Terry"},
    new PetCategoryOwner { Owner = "Liam", PetCategory = "Chartreux"}
};
```

**Expected values**

| Owner | Pet Category | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Higa | Terry | A |
| Higa | Charlotte | A |
| Oliver | Terry | A |
| Oliver | Charlotte | A |
| Oliver | Chausie | B |
| Price | Chausie | B |
| Liam | Terry | C |
| Liam | Chartreux | C |

```cs
var petCategoriesOwners = new List<PetCategoriesOwners>()
{
    new PetCategoriesOwners()
    {
        PetCategories = new List<string>() { "Terry", "Charlotte" },
        Owners = new List<string>() { "Oliver", "Higa" }
    },
    new PetCategoriesOwners()
    {
        PetCategories = new List<string>() { "Chausie" },
        Owners = new List<string>() { "Oliver", "Price" }
    },
    new PetCategoriesOwners()
    {
        PetCategories = new List<string>() { "Chartreux", "Terry" },
        Owners = new List<string>() { "Liam" }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not clear how you want to group them? grouping by PetCategories would give you PetCategory and list of owners, what type of grouping you need?

Comment: I would like to group by the combinations that they have, if the owners has same combinations with pet category, it should be on the sameobject.

Comment: so group by petCategoryOwner.GroupBy(g => new { g.PetCategory, g.Owner })

Comment: this code will not work, this is like categorizing owners who have same category combinations of their pets, but your code is like giving me the unique combination of pet category and owner.

Comment: your last output set is not correct "Chartreux", "Terry" :
by grouping just PetCategory will return a set of owners per that category.
so liam would be in 2 places Chartreux and Terry

Comment: But Liam doesn't have Chartreux, so he won't be on the first group.

Comment: @MingTsai - I don't understand what rules you're applying for the groupings. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve your problem you need to do two steps: group by owners and merge owners based on the fact other group's set is a subset of current owner. You can try to achieve it by running below LINQ query:

```
public class PetCategoriesOwners
{
    public List<string> PetCategories { get; set; }
    public List<string> Owners { get; set; }
}

var petCategoriesOwners = petCategoryOwner
    .GroupBy(x => x.Owner)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Owner = x.Key,
        Categories = x.Select(y => y.PetCategory)
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Categories.Count())
    .Aggregate(new List<PetCategoriesOwners>(), (acc, current) =>
    {
        var currentCategories = current.Categories.ToList();
        var matches = acc.Where(group => group.PetCategories.All(x => currentCategories.Contains(x)));

        foreach(var match in matches)
        {
            match.Owners.Add(current.Owner);
            currentCategories = currentCategories.Except(match.PetCategories).ToList();
        }

        if (currentCategories.Any())
        {
            acc.Add(
                new PetCategoriesOwners() { 
                    Owners = new List<string>() { current.Owner }, 
                    PetCategories = currentCategories 
                });
        }

        return acc;
    });
```

So it's important to group by `Owner`, process groups in ascending order in terms of length. The `Aggregate` method basically tries to find if previosly entered item overlaps with currently processed one. If it happens then we take those intersecting elements, add owner there and remove those from current element. If any element is left then we create own group for such owner.

Edit: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MFK2kv)

Comment: I can't get this code to compile. Can I confirm it runs and can you show the output?

Comment: @Enigmativity sure, updated my answer and added .NET Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer is based on a false interpretation of the question post. In it, I have assumed that `petCategoriesOwners` is an *input* and that the content of the table containing the `Group` column is the expected *output*.

---

You could achieve what you want to do by using a combination of [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0), [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0), [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) and [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0) from *System.Linq*.

Slightly simplified, by using `int`s for the group value rather than `char`, this is a possible implemenation:

```
public class GroupedOwnerAndPetCategory
{
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string PetCategory { get; set; }
    public int Group { get; set; }
}
```

```csharp
var grouped = petCategoriesOwners
    .SelectMany((ownerPetMix, index) => petCategoryOwner
        .Where(ownerPetPair =>
                ownerPetMix.Owners.Contains(ownerPetPair.Owner) &&
                ownerPetMix.PetCategories.Contains(ownerPetPair.PetCategory))
        .Select(ownerPetPair => new GroupedOwnerAndPetCategory
            {
                Owner = ownerPetPair.Owner,
                PetCategory = ownerPetPair.PetCategory,
                Group = index
            }))
    .ToList();
```

Using your example input, `grouped` contains the following entries:

```
Higa      Terry        0
Higa      Charlotte    0
Oliver    Terry        0
Oliver    Charlotte    0
Oliver    Chausie      1
Price     Chausie      1
Liam      Terry        2
Liam      Chartreux    2
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HKFM5C).

Comment: The `petCategoriesOwners` should be empty, due to is expected value, so when I remove the variable en the `example fiddle` it is not working.

Comment: @MingTsai So, `petCategoriesOwners` is actually your expected output? I understood your question to mean that the table directly _before_ the `petCategoriesOwners`, which is introduced with the title _Expected values_, was in fact your expected output. You are right that if `petCategoriesOwners` is initially empty, this approach will absolutely not work, seeing as I understood it to be an input.

Comment: Yes, the `petCategoriesOwners` is my expected output. Anywhere thanks for response me.